# How to disable OK button in "Browse For Folder" dialog in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

I need to disable the OK button in "Browse For Folder" dialog if

1. A file (doesn't) exists (preferably with `FileExists`)
2. An existing reg key (doesn't) points to that directory (preferably with `RegKeyExists` `RegValueExists`)

I do know how to achieve a more-or-less same result by disabling the Next button on wpSelectDir page, but I think "Browse For Folder" dialog would be much more convenient, if it's possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not possible because the [`BrowseForFolder`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_browseforfolder) function uses internally the [`SHBrowseForFolder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762115%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function for the dialog. And that dialog can interact with this function caller only through the passed callback, which is [`implemented internally`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/is-5_5_5/Projects/BrowseFunc.pas#L39) and not exposed anywhere.